# Gaussian integers and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

a). In the ring of Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i] = \{a + bi \mid a, b ∈ Z\}$, describe the ideal $\langle i\rangle$.

b). In the ring of Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$, show that $2 \in J$ where $J$ is the ideal $\langle i+ 1\rangle$.

I'm having trouble doing this one. So far I know that the ideal $\langle i\rangle=\{(a+bi)i \mid (a+bi)\in \Bbb Z[i] \}$ based on the definition. For b),
$$
\langle i+ 1\rangle=\{(a+bi)(i+1) \mid (a+bi)\in \Bbb Z[i] \} = \{(a + b)i + (a-b) \mid (a+bi)\in \Bbb Z[i] \}.
$$

I'm very confused on where to go from with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2=(1-i)(1+i)$, which is enough to have $2\in J$.

For the part a) you can see that $(a+bi)i=-b+ai$ which can be seen a anti-clock 90º rotation of the Gaussian grid.